# How to edit only opening tag or closing tag

Tags: java, xml, xhtml

How to edit only opening tag or closing tag of an XML file using Java?

Or how to create a valid one. since java is creating automatic closing tags with the same name and I have

```
<img id="2" src="item1.jpg">
```

What I get is

```
<img id="2" src="item1.jpg">  bla bla </img id="2" src="item1.jpg">
```

and the browser expect for a `>` after `<img` to close it

```
 doc.createElement("img id=\"2\" src=\"item1.jpg\"" );
```

Don't worry about parsing special characters to XML, I fixed that problem.

The resume of my problem is that i try to create or edit a nametag to get an image and write this line into a XML or XHTML file, and since there will be a lot of tags and files to modify I don't want to do it manualy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't create the element like that. The argument to [`createElement()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html#createElement%28java.lang.String%29) is called `tagName`, and is only that (`"img"` in your case).

You need to call [`setAttribute(String name, String value)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Element.html#setAttribute%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) on the returned `Element`.

Comment: that makes sense :) THANK YOOUU!!

Comment: @IlieMihai - The correct way here for the question asker to thank the answerer is to accept the answer by clicking on the big tick to the left of the answer.